# Is it possible to add a line break in Flowgarithm?

Tags: ascii, keyword

I want to add a line break in the Output Statement in Flowgarithm. For example, I want:

> Line 1
>
> Line 2

NOT:

> Line 1 Line 2

I have been working in the program, and it does not accept many special symbols, such as `|, <<, /,` etc...

I have tried scouring the website (http://www.flowgorithm.org/index.htm) to no avail.

I have found, however, a section on said website, under Documentation>Documentation>Output, there is a section that has details about "newline", "first", and "last".

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `ToChar(13)` in between the lines.

Like this:

[image: Output command]

This gives an output like:

[image]

`13` is the ASCII code for carriage return. Hope this is what you need.